# how to enumerate over columns in pandas and calculate the difference of each columns with the rest of columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my dataset I have X_Coordinate and Y_Coordinate, in order to calculate the closeness centrality I need to calculate the sum of euclidien distance between a each node and the other nodes. I tried this:

```
for ind, row in allclosetA.iterrows():
    allclosetA.loc[ind, "Dist6_71"] = (row['ID71'] - row['ID6']) ** 2
    allclosetA.loc[ind, "Dist6_3"] = (row['ID3'] - row['ID6'])  ** 2
    allclosetA.loc[ind, "Dist71_3"] = (row['ID3'] - row['ID71']) ** 2
    allclosetA.loc[ind, "Dist71_6"] = (row['ID6'] - row['ID71'])  ** 2
    allclosetA.loc[ind, "Dist3_71"] = (row['ID71'] - row['ID3']) ** 2
    allclosetA.loc[ind, "Dist3_6"] = (row['ID6'] - row['ID3'])  ** 2
```

It works well, but in my case the columns change and also the IDs so I need to run the code automatically to get the results as per the below output.
[image: output]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but since you are acessing your X and y coordinate through 'row', why dont you do the same for your distance value.

So instead of:

```
allclosetA.loc[ind, "Dist6_71"] = (row['ID71'] - row['ID6']) ** 2
```

do

```
row["Dist6_71"] = (row['ID71'] - row['ID6']) ** 2
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I used loc to create new colum including the results to use it after. Now the problem is I want to avoid this nomination of colum ['ID71'] because sometimes I can get 3 columns or 4 columns with different ID. So what I want to do is to calculate difference of rows based on length of columns using this ( for i in  len(TransC.columns):) and then calculate the difference. example of 3 columns:  [col1-col2, col1-col3], [col2-col1, col2-col3], [col3-col1, col3-col2]. I hope that is clear

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution that can run it for all columns where: 
D presents the coordinates of the points (10 nodes) and A presents the coordinates of the destination nodes(4 nodes)

```
>>Dist = distance.cdist(D, A, 'euclidean')

output will be as :

array([[12133.60222432, 14226.66590047, 13633.17137862, 11551.40491604],
       [11717.38072204, 14530.80182803, 13388.81377667, 11638.00260056],
       [11857.04168551, 14289.78968555, 13444.84417939, 11495.22703937],
       [12170.37182026, 14246.57297414, 13665.43033544, 11578.04979044],
       [11855.10630493, 14310.59694105, 13448.47824213, 11509.09643289],
       [11819.37984252, 14307.15862737, 13420.39712489, 11495.84805381],
       [11703.70538731, 14390.6746685 , 13349.46136896, 11525.60225697],
       [11839.17386385, 14305.76790429, 13435.17081908, 11500.84335837],
       [12374.10141775, 14259.01528361, 13815.13724876, 11669.28728949],
       [11701.63634533, 14442.87630321, 13358.71317513, 11565.26437527]])
```